# Linear transformation $P: V \times W \to V \times W$ which is a projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V and W be vector spaces. Is it possible to find a linear transformation $P: V \times W \to V \times W$ which is a projection, such that im(P) is isomorphic to V and kernel of P is isomorphic to W. I believe so, but could someone help in providing a specific example or approach? Thanks!

Comment: Try projecting onto the $V$ coordinate, $(v,w)\mapsto (v,0)$.

Comment: Note that $V \times W$ is the same thing that $V \oplus W$. And a direct sum gives a projection.